# How to filter Array in array key-value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've the following structure.

```
[
    {
        "Variants": [
            {
                "SellPrice": "75.00",
                "VariantID": "10",
                "VariantName": "1 L",
                "InCart": "2",
                "MRP": "115.00",
                "VariantImagePath": "/images/ruchi/710_10.png"
            },
            {
                "SellPrice": "410.00",
                "VariantID": "113",
                "VariantName": "5 L",
                "InCart": "1",
                "MRP": "485.00",
                "VariantImagePath": "/images/ruchi/710_113.png"
            },
            {
                "SellPrice": "1080.00",
                "VariantID": "219",
                "VariantName": "15L - Jar",
                "InCart": "0",
                "MRP": "1275.00",
                "VariantImagePath": "/images/ruchi/710_219.png"
            }
        ],
        "SubCategoryID": "32",
        "ProductImagePath": "/images/ruchi/710.png",
        "SubCategoryName": "Soyabean Oil",
        "BrandName": "Ruchi",
        "ProductID": "710",
        "BrandID": "117",
        "ProductName": "Ruchi soya oil"
    },
    {
        "Variants": [
            {
                "SellPrice": "58.00",
                "VariantID": "23",
                "VariantName": "900 GM",
                "InCart": "1",
                "MRP": "60.00",
                "VariantImagePath": "/images/mtr/771_23.png"
            }
        ],
        "SubCategoryID": "110",
        "ProductImagePath": "/images/mtr/771.png",
        "SubCategoryName": "Vermicelli",
        "BrandName": "MTR",
        "ProductID": "771",
        "BrandID": "167",
        "ProductName": "Seviyan Vermicelli"
    }
]
```

Want to filter all the data where Variants.InCart value is > 0.

In this case output will be

```
ProductID   VariantID   InCart
710         113         1
710         10          2
771         23          1
```

and this is my loop.

```
<tr ng-repeat="Item in ProductService.Products | <what should be filter condition here>">
    <td>{{Item.ProductID}} {{Item.Variants.VariantID}} {{Item.Variants.InCart}}</td>
</tr>
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you already read the documentation of the filter directive? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Also it seems strange for me to have an InCart value of type string and a comparison against number 0. That does not look good.

Comment: Yes i checked that. They have not given any condition for array in array in that.

Comment: What I suggest you, create a fiddle, so that one can play with it to solve your issue.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal if you are struggling with angular filter, than is it possible for you to filter your data inside controller itself. I think this is also the way.

Comment: @Ved Can you please share a link if you have any.

Comment: No.. I dont have link. I can share you DEMO code, that may help you..

Comment: var fltr = $scope.data[0].Variants.filter(function (ele){
     return (ele.InCart!="0") ;
    } );
    console.log(fltr);

Answer (score 1):

```html
<tr ng-repeat="Item in ProductService.Products | filter:customArrayFilter">
    <td>{{Item.ProductID}} {{Item.Variants.VariantID}} {{Item.Variants.InCart}}</td>
</tr>
```

```
$scope.customArrayFilter = function (item) {
      return (item.InCart > 0);
    };
```

You can add custom filter like this..

Comment: But how loop will go to next variant of the same item?

Comment: is that array in array?

Comment: please create plunkr or fiddle